# Почему не работает remove(); в AJAX

Tags: jquery

У меня есть несколько `<iframe>`, я хочу каждый проверить статус если iframe умерла ссылка (не рабочая ссылка) - то удалить Iframe со страницы. Я могу получить alert(), все работает. Но я не могу послать команду удалить данный iframe. Что здесь не так?

```js
$('iframe').each(function() {

 

  var urlExists = function(url, callback) {

      if ( ! $.isFunction(callback)) {
         throw Error('Not a valid callback');
      }   

      $.ajax({
          type: 'HEAD',
          url: url,
          success: $.proxy(callback, this, true),
          error: $.proxy(callback, this, false)      
      });

  };

  urlExists( $(this).attr('src') , function(success) {
      if (success) {
          //alert('Yay!');
      } else {
          alert('Oh no! Oh no! Oh no! Oh no! Oh no! Oh no!');
          $(this).remove();
      }
  });

});
```

```html
<iframe width="1762" height="251" src="https://videofile.online/embed/620897/" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

<br>

<iframe width="1762" height="251" src="https://videofile.online/embed/620897/" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

<br>

<iframe width="1762" height="251" src="https://vide2ofile.online/embed/620897/" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

У вас this не указывает на iframe т.к. находится в другом контексте, грубо говоря.

Замените `$('iframe').each(function() {` на `$('iframe').each(function(index, item) {`

И удаление `$(item).remove();`

Comment: Огромное спасибо!! Теперь я понимаю  jQuery сильнее лучше.